# Deploy React App Return `This page is using the development build of React`despite already executing `npm run build`

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

currently i'm create a simple react apps as you can see in https://selly-midtrans.herokuapp.com/ but when i deploy it , it gave me some errors [image]

and i've follow this https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build so i run `heroku run npm run build` but it seem doesn't change anything in my production

any advice guys ? i'll really appreciate any advice from you

Comment: try `npm set NODE_ENV "production"` and if that doesn't work try `npm set production true`

Comment: hi sir thanks for your advice but unfortunately the error still appear , i've add `NODE_ENV = production` and `PRODUCTION = true`

Comment: navigate to the project folder in your terminal and do `npm config edit` find the lines with `NODE_ENV` and `PRODUCTION` and confirm that they are properly set

Answer (score 0):

Default heroku buildpack will run `npm start` which will start development server.

You need to use `https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack` which will actually build the production version of your app and serve static assets.